# Объясните, пожалуйста почему такой вывод на консоль, булевые выражения

Tags: python, строки, логические-выражения

```
print('kk' and '') #вывод пустая строка
print('' or 'gh') #gh
print('' or [] or {}) #{}
f = 'first'
s = 'second'
print(1 and f or s) #first
print(0 and f or s) #second
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Результат операторов `and` и `or` в Питоне *не определяется как `True` или `False`*.

Он равен **первому** или **второму операнду**.

Именно этому, которого логическое значение *нужно ешё определить*, чтобы обыкновенный результат логической операции *с математической точки зрения* (т.е. `True` или `False`) *был уже знаком*.

(Сm. документацию [6.11. Boolean operations](http://6.11.%20Boolean%20operations).)

Например в вашей первой строке

```
'kk' and ''
```

определится в первую очередь логическое значение `'kk'` - это `True` так как строка не пустая. (См. [4.1. Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).)

Это *не хватит* для вычисление *всякого логического выражения* (хватило бы, когда бы это было `False`), и так *нужно ещё определить логическое значение второго операнда* - `''` - последнего, и так *он* будет результатом вашего выражения `'kk' and ''`.